# Hi Need some information for ubuntu installation

Tags: drivers

I have this hardware configuration of laptop, Please let me know for which version I have to proceed for UBUNTU installation:

```
Acer One S1002-15XR 10.1-inch Laptop Information:
Technical Details
Brand   : Acer
Series  : One
Colour  : IRON
Item Height : 26 Millimeters
Item Width  : 25.8 Centimeters
Screen Size : 10.1 Inches
Item Weight : 1.2 Kg
Product Dimensions  : 19.4 x 25.8 x 2.6 cm
Item model number   : S1002-15XR
Processor Brand : Intel
Processor Type  : Atom
Processor Speed : 1.33 GHz
RAM Size    : 2 GB
Memory Technology   : DDR3L
Hard Drive Size : 32 GB
Hard Disk Technology    : Mechanical Hard Drive
Graphics Coprocessor    : Intel Integrated Graphics
Connectivity Type   : Wi-Fi, Bluetooth-V4
Wireless Type   : 802.11bgn
Number of Microphone Ports  : 1
Wattage : 10 Watts
Hardware Platform   : LAPTOP
Operating System    : Windows 10
Average Battery Life : (in hours)   4
Number of Lithium Ion Cells : 2
Included Components Net-tablet PC, Battery, AC Adapter and Keyboard Dock
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a 32-bit version of Ubuntu, regardless of version.
This would be the i386 version as described by downloads.

I would also use Lubuntu. You have very low-end specs, and Lubuntu is very light.